# Rows into column with Header

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am working on a script where I need to print the output of below command and get it in an excel sheet:
Command is:

```
ifconfig -a |grep -i bond
```

Output is:

```
bond0   Link encap: Ethernet Hwwaddr: B1:B2:X1:X2:X3:X4
bond1   Link encap: Ethernet Hwwaddr: B1:B2:X1:X2:X4:X5
```

This command I need to run on multiple server using for loop.
However, I need to bring in excel sheet in below format:

```
Server Name    Bond Name    Link Encap     Hwaddr
xxxxxx         bond0        Ethernet       B1:B2:X1:X2:X3:X4
xxxxxx         bond1        Ethernet       B1:B2:X1:X2:X4:X5
```

Comment: `ifconfig -a | grep -ie bond -e "server nane"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with bash shell.  It will give you CSV output which is easily imported into Excel.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'Server Name,Bond Name,Link Encap,Hwaddr\n'

for line in "$(ifconfig -a|grep -i bond)"
do
  echo -n $(hostname),
  set $line
  echo $1,${3//encap:/},$5
done
```

This will produce your desired output running on a single server.  Since you don't mention how you plan to run it on multiple servers to generate the data, you may need to alter this slightly to suit your needs.

Comment: No sane mammalian that uses unix/linux and bash would ever use excel.

Comment: Well of course not!  ;-)  Just giving the OP the data asked for in a format he could use in the application he wanted.

Comment: I missed that indeed.

Comment: I am running it on multiple server inside for loop.

Comment: If you will be running it manually on each server, the above should work.  If you are going to fire off something from one host to SSH to other servers to get this information, just wrap another loop around the code here to connect to your remote hosts.

Comment: it's giving error :bad substitution. Please advice

Comment: I tried it :#!/bin/bash
printf 'Server Name, Bond Name, Link Encap, HWaddr \n'
for i in $(cat filename)
do
BOND=$(ssh username@$i '(/sbin/ifconfig -a |grep -i bond | awk '{print$1,$3,$5}'))
echo $i,$BOND
done    it's giving error :bad substitution. Please advice

Comment: It's a little hard to tell with the formatting here.  I see unmatched single-quotes.  I also don't think you want the ( ) in your ssh string.  Try:
BOND=$(ssh username@$i "/sbin/ifconfig -a |grep -i bond | awk '{print$1,$3,$5}'")   *** that's a single-quote followed by a double-quote right before the closing ) ***